# how to send plain text only using nfc android beam

Tags: android, nfc, ndef, android-beam

I'm using Eclipse-Android and creating an application that is supposed to send plain text using this code:

EDIT:

```
private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

    NdefRecord[] records = { createTextRecord(text, "yes") };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();
    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}

private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}
```

But what I read with my arduino is the package name and the Google Play store link. how can I configure it that the only message that will be read is the plain text?

Comment: You cannot beam plain text. You can only beam one or more NDEF records.

Comment: does it mean i can only beam either play store link or package name?

Comment: Your question does not incude the relevant code! Where is `createRecord()` called? How do you activate/register for Beam? WHat device are you using?

Comment: i edit my post and add additional code

Comment: That's still not the relevant code! Are you implementing SNEP/Android Beam on the Arduino side? `Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);` looks as if you are trying to access the Arduino side as NFC tag -- that's certainly not the code for Android Beam.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code to create text record and this works perfectly fine

```
public static NdefRecord createTextRecord(String payload, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
    byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
    byte[] textBytes = payload.getBytes(utfEncoding);
    int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
    char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);
    byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
    data[0] = (byte) status;
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);
    NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,
    NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
    return record;
}
```

Do add following intent-filters in your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Visit: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html for more information on NFC